# How many Returns with every() and other iterative methods?

Tags: javascript

This is a general question for some of Javascripts array methods.  Take the following as an example:

```
var numbers = new Array(12, 5, 8, 130, 44);

function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
  return element >= 10;
}

alert(numbers.every(isBigEnough));
```

This will return FALSE.
When I first read about these methods (such as every, some, filter, forEach, map) that iterate over an array, I thought that the function isBigEnough would be called for each element.  So in the above example, I would have thought that isBigEnough would be called five separate times with 5 return values.  Clearly this is not that case.

I'd now guess that the method calls the function 5 times, but the Return doesn't actually return anything until either all elements are TRUE, or until a FALSE is found.

Does anyone know of a flowchart or graphic that shows the process or flow of these iterative methods?

thanks

Comment: `every()` will stop as soon as one of the callbacks returns `false`.  Did you really read closely [the documentation of that function?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: I sort of did, although reading it 2 more times has helped.  I didn't phrase my question very well, as I wasn't really guessing.  But I was just looking for a graphic flowchart of the method. Maybe such a flowchart is too self-obvious and not required though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla documentation for these methods is very good. For `every` and `some` it specifically states that the methods return immediately on finding a falsy/truthy value.

> **every**
>
> The every method executes the provided callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a falsy value (a value that becomes false when converted to a Boolean). If such an element is found, the every method immediately returns false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

> **some**
>
> some() executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. If such an element is found, some() immediately returns true

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Yes, I see that. I agree that the documentation is good. I was just wondering if there were known graphics showing the flow of the method.  Maybe my question is looking for something obscure or too self obvious.

Comment: @DougSmith, I don't think there's enough variation that shows the need, plus generally speaking the functions do what one would expect.. they end as soon as they know the answer.